# dpkg error from /etc/default/grub when upgrading

Tags: dpkg

I have a 22.04.2 version of Jammy Jellyfish installed on my machine. When I attempt to do an update and upgrade, I am getting the following error. Do any of you, by any chance, know what might have caused this and suggest how to fix it? Many Thanks

```
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic (5.19.0-38.39~22.04.1) ...

/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic

I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 36: /etc/default/grub: bash:: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic package post-installation script subpro
cess returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` command as Baa suggested:

```
hetrengzy@hefto-Ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/default/grub

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=45
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"


bash: line 1: J: command not found
```

Can you suggest what to do with this please? Many thanks

Comment: It's saying that the line `bash::` is inside the file `/etc/default/grub` and it probably shouldn't be. Please run `cat /etc/default/grub` then edit your question and add the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an additional line added to `/etc/default/grub` that's causing the problem `bash: line 1: J: command not found`. Not sure how it got there but just remove it.

1. Use the command `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` to open this file in a text editor.
2. Locate the line that says `bash: line 1: J: command not found` at the end.
3. Remove the entire line, be careful not to modify anything else in the file.
4. Save and close the editor.
5. Try updating again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Baa, I fix the issue as you advised and the error seems to be gone.

Comment: no problem glad that worked 